# Jquery ModalDialog Hides Behind IFrame....

Tags: jquery

I want to show a jquery modal dialog box over iframe currently it goes behind the iframe. so how can i show the jquery modal dialog box over iframe with re-sizing, dragging features.

***HTML CODE***

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<iframe style="width: 99%; height: 759px;" src="http://unfccc.int/resource/docs/convkp/kpeng.pdf"></iframe>
```

***Jquery/Javascript Code***

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        show: {
            effect: "clip",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "clip",
            duration: 1000
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try adding `?wmode=transparent` to the end of the URL for `IFRAME`.

Comment: try using the appendTo option to append to the iframe

Comment: I have tried your code here http://jsbin.com/ozEgiBO/1/edit with jQuery and jQueryUI and it seems to work?

Comment: I have checked it out : my code is perfectly working in Google Chrome And Mozilla Firefox because both the browsers have its internal pdf viewer but the same code is not working in IE and Safari since they depend on adobe